# how can I upload the web application "JSF" to Server GlassFish online?

Tags: jsf, web-applications, netbeans, glassfish, java-server

i have a web application project "JSF" on "Netbeans IDE"
How can I upload my project to a server in order to start work online

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use FTP (File Transfert Protocol) to do this, just take a look a t this tutorial using FileZille FTP Client :
http://www.4templates.com/tutorials/uploading-files-with-ftp-and-filezilla/

Then you must deploy your app on the GlassFish server, look at this tutorial :
http://blog.c2b2.co.uk/2014/03/writing-and-deploying-simple-web.html